# I'm getting JINJA not found error in a Python program

Tags: python, jinja2, blogs, pelican

[image]
I'm trying to set up a blog using pelican. After running the initial steps and setting Theme= Flex, This error keeps popping. But if I change the Theme to something else like resume, etc. no error arises.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What **version** of Pelican are you using?
`JINJA_ENVIRONMENT` was introduced in v3.7.0, replacing `JINJA_EXTENSIONS`.
So if you by any chance installed a version older than v3.7.0, the template uses a variable which is not set by default.